# Error installing eclipse+pydev on windowXP

Tags: python, eclipse, installation, pydev

I ran into a problem installing eclipse+pydev on Window XP. Eclipse version is 4.2.0 and I have Python 2.7.3. I get the following error message:

[image: Error message]

could anyone help me out?

thanx in advance!

Comment: you do have python installed? whats the path you installed it to?

Comment: I checked C:\Python27\python.exe , Django also installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure python is in your path variable
this is typically at C:\Python27\python.exe

right click my computer , select properties, select Advanced System Settings, Select "Environmental Variables" .

Find the variable named path

edit it and include the path to your python executable (Normally "C:\Python27\")

if you open your command window ("cmd" console whatever)
you should be able to type python and open the python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure PyDev so it knows where your interpreter is.  In Window>Preferences, select PyDev>Interpreter - Python in the left side menu.  Add a new entry in the top pane on the right side that points to the location of your Python exe.  This is the equivalent action to setting your Python path for tools outside of Eclipse.

Comment: oh yeah that works too ... but i think the auto-configure searches your path variable so if you add your Python install location to the path that works also

Comment: Can you re-run auto-configure after PyDev is already installed?

Comment: I told you.  Start in the Window menu in Eclipse.